# General Structure of GAM (General Additive Models)

Tags: r, regression, estimation, inference

I am trying to better understand how GAM (General Additive Models) work. I am reading the following reference: https://m-clark.github.io/generalized-additive-models/application.html

In a standard linear regression problem, interpreting the parameter estimates are straightforward:

[image]

Over here, the model can be interpreted as: **Overall = 182.32 * Income + 234.11 * Edu + 27.01 * Health + 121.18**

**Question:** However, I am not sure how to interpret a similar GAM :

[image]

In this case, can the final GAM be interpreted as: **Overall = 7.593 * Income + 6.204 * Education + 1.00 * Health** ? Based on the p-values, is "Health" the only "significant" parameter in this GAM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> In this case, can the final GAM be interpreted as: Overall = 7.593 * Income + 6.204 * Education + 1.00 * Health ?

No, not at all. That is the formula of a linear model but your smoothers are most likely not going to be linear. Also you forgot the Intercept which is estimated to be 471.
The `lm` output includes estimates, which the GAM output does not. Its first column contains `edf`: effective degrees of freedom, not estimates. The smoothers will return a different estimate for every value of `Income`, `Edu` and `Health`. You can plot the smoothers [(more)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843897/6503141) if you want to gain further insight.

> Based on the p-values, is "Health" the only "significant" parameter in this GAM?

No. `Health` is the only parameter which is not statistically significant.

Comment: @ Bernhard: Thank you for your answer! Suppose for some new observations, income = 20000, health = 5, and education = 4 . Based on the fitted GAM, can you please tell me the formula required to calculate the estimated value of the "overall" variable? Thank you!

Comment: First: the necessary information is not contained in the output. Second: It would be really hard to compute that for yourself. Use the `predict` function or read the smoother values from the graph and add them. Complexity of computation is one of the tradeoffs of GAM over OLS.